# XIB - ViewController communication

Tags: swift, delegates, xib, viewcontroller

I load a view from a `XIB` into a `ViewController`: the XIB is an `IBOutlet` of the viewcontroller.

The view contains two `UITextFields` and a `UIButton`. The button must invoke a function in the viewcontroller.

The textfields should respond to the typical textfields delegates, and in any case, communicate with the "parent" ViewController in a bidirectional way.

What's the best way to do this?

While it's quite clear for me how to deal with the button (I can use a delegate in the `UIView` class and conform the viewcontroller to the delegate), it's unclear for me how to deal with the textfield delegates.

Comment: You can use the same approach of the button with the text fields, what's the problem?

Comment: No problem, I thought there was something less "convoluted", that is some way to automatically "propagate" textfield events to the viewcontroller, without having to do it manually

Comment: You can make the view controller the delegate of the textfields directly, so you don't need to create custom methods and propagate them.

Comment: The textfields are in the UIView, in a XIB. Are you suggesting to totally remove the XIB and create the view directly in the viewcontroller?

Comment: You can "expose" the text fields from the uiview, so the view controller can access them and set the delegate.

Comment: The textfields are currently exposed: what I don't understand of your reply is how the viewcontroller can set the delegate upon them, sorry, I never did it   :-)

Comment: Oh, maybe now I understand: something like myView.myField.delegate = self, then conform the VC to the textfield delegate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164168/discussion-between-rico-crescenzio-and-3000).

Comment: Ok, sorry for not partecipating to the chat, I have no time: I avoided delegates and simply used addTarget to the exposed fields (it worked perfectly, thanks)